# Does Disqus have public events to attach to?

Tags: javascript, events, disqus, mutation-events

I need to perform some re-calculations after disqus form gets an update. A new comment, error message just to name a few. In essence any event that causes the Disqus iframe to expand vertically. Checked the API, but didn't find any public events. Seems like the events are not publicly accessibly atm. So the first question is – does Disqus have any public events to attach to?

The second would be – if I have no way to attach to events from Disqus I wonder would MutationEvent do the trick for me taking into account that Disqus stuff is within an iFrame?

Comment: Have you ever found the answer? :D

Answer (score 2):

Best I have come up with so far

```
function disqus_config() {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function() { trackComment(); }];
}
```

from here: 
http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-how-can-i-capture-disqus-commenting-activity-in-my-own-analytics-tool-

Doing a `console.log(DISQUS)` in the chrome console shows the disqus object, and there are other callbacks mentioned

```
_callbacks: Object
  switches.changed: Array[2]
  window.click: Array[2]
  window.hashchange: Array[2]
  window.resize: Array[2]
  window.scroll: Array[2]
```

and `on` and `trigger` methods

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about public events for Disqus in particular, but if you just need to monitor changes to an iframe's height, here's one way:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
var iframeHeight = iframe.clientHeight;

setInterval(function() {
    if(iframe.clientHeight != iframeHeight) {
        // My iframe's height has changed - do some stuff!

        iframeHeight = iframe.clientHeight;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Granted, it's basically a hack. But it should work!

Comment: Yeah, this is a hack indeed. Moreover not very elegant one as for me – 1s delay in adjusting the height is not really what I want. Especially since I will use computing power to poll every second no matter whether the iframe has been changed or not.But thanks for the snippet anyway.

Comment: When it is dry for a long time, hail may be welcome. This solution can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they don't have any public events documented (as far I can tell). But, application is triggering a lot of events on its parent window. So it's possible to listen to them and make some actions. You can do that with following snippet:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    // if message is not from discus frame, leap out
    if (event.origin != 'https://disqus.com' && event.origin != 'http://disqus.com') return;

    // parse data
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

    // do stuff with data. type of action can be detected with data.name 
    // property ('ready', 'resize', 'fakeScroll', etc) 
}, false);
```

In webkit based browsers it works just fine. With firefox there might be some issues. With IE... well, I don't have any IE on hand to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find list of available events in [embed payload](https://discussdisqus.disqus.com/embed.js):

```
callbacks:{
    preData:[],
    preInit:[],
    onInit:[],
    afterRender:[],
    onReady:[],
    onNewComment:[],
    preReset:[],
    onPaginate:[],
    onIdentify:[],
    beforeComment:[]
}
```

I haven't found any documentation (except [example for `onNewComment`](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717088-capture-disqus-commenting-activity-via-callbacks)), so you need guess how they works from event name.

You can use them in this way:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [
        function() { 
            // your code
        }
    ];
};
```

or

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = this.callbacks.onNewComment || [];
    this.callbacks.onNewComment.push(function() { 
        // your code
    });
}
```

---

On the side note, I found them completely useless for detecting change in height of comments iframe. I ended with using `ResizeSensor` from [`css-element-queries`](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries).